# Как выбрать пороги корреляции при отборе признаков?

Tags: pandas, анализ-данных, статистика, анализ

**Всем привет.**

Решаю задачу кластеризации и *моя цель - уменьшить размерность данных*, т.е. избавится от ненужных признаков (не использую PCA, т.к. хочу сохранить оригинальные фичи для последующего анализа).

На скрине приведена корреляция Спирмена между признаками:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я планирую выбрать верхний порог (например 0,75) и нижний порог (например -0,75).
И если корреляция между двумя признаками выходит за пределы интервалы (0,75, -0,75), то я рандомно удаляю один из них.

**Вопрос1:**
Так отбирать признаки в принципе корректно или нет?

**Вопрос2:**
Как выбрать данные пороги?

Comment: Корректно или нет, зависит от данных. По сути бывает, что это работает, бывает, что нет, каждый раз индивидуальный подход.

Comment: Ну так то корректно так делать, но какой будет результат - неизвестно, надо пробовать. Но вообще мне казалось, что отбрасывают обычно признаки с корреляцией больше 0.9 и больше, но точно не помню. В любом случае нужно пробовать. Вы попробуйте разные подходы, да посмотрите результат. Только так и делают, строгих правил нет. Может оказаться и так, что этот метод даст плохие результаты при любом пороге (ну, кроме может 0.99, например).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу нахождения порогов по корреляции - в свое время использовал функцию, которую таскал от "данных" к "данным"

```
def correl(X_train, thresh):
    cor = X_train.corr()
    c1 = cor.stack().sort_values(ascending=False).drop_duplicates()
    all_cor = c1[c1.values != 1]
    return all_cor[abs(all_cor) > thresh]
```

здесь на вход подается ваш фрейм и порог.

(учитывается и положительное и отрицательное значение, поэтому указывайте только положительное)

На выходе получаете коррелирующие столбцы и их коэффициент.